Grooves or Rings on a Jig
I hope you're all doing well.
I'm currently modeling this very intricate design that has a round plate in the center. This round plate it's supposed to have 5 grooves/rings of 1mm in width and about 4mm in depth, akin to a bullseye. There is also a cross of the same width and depth that cuts through all 5 rings, merging at the 5th ring. I've attached an image of what I'm trying to describe as a visual aid.
To say that I am having an extremely difficult time would be an understament. Could any of you smarter folks share some of your knowledge with this?
Thank you all in advanced.
Much obliged,
Eldritch


Use your image as reference image, create a circle (the more vertices the rounder it will be), extrude it inwards several times so that it matches the image:

Fill the center, join the vertices (J):

Select all these edges:

Bevel (CtrlB), you can precisely set the Width in the Operator Box:

Extrude up the whole mesh, again you can precisely set the move:

Select the edges and extrude up again:


The OP mentions depth. Shouldn't your last operation be going the other way on the Z axis? That is if I haven't misunderstood something :)

oh ok maybe, but it is still the same kind of operation

Wicked. I couldn:t have asked for a better explanation. Thank you very much for taking time to break it down the way you did. I just tried it and it did exactly what I needed. Is tricks like these that make learning Blender so much fun.
Much obliged!

No worries on the inversed direction. I managed to figure it out. Thank you!
